# Scala Futures - keep main thread alive without explicitly setting time delay

Tags: scala

I am starting to play around with Scala Futures for the first time. I'm interested in a non-blocking (i.e. not `Await.Result`) solution to keep my main thread alive while I run some asynchronous database queries. Using the information I've found so far on callbacks, I've put together something like this.

```
def miniFuturesExample(conn: DatabaseConnection)
{
    val f1 = Future { runQuery(conn) }
    f1.onComplete
    {
        case Success(result) => println(result.next())
        case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
    }
    // do some other stuff
    Thread.sleep(2000)
}
```

What I would prefer to avoid is specifying a time value for `Thread.sleep`. The reason I don't want to hardcode this in is because I am not always sure how long the `runQuery` method will take to complete. I would like to find a non-blocking solution to keep the main thread alive until the `onComplete` block of `f1` has been triggered.

Comment: You can do anything you want before you call `Await.Result`, which sounds like a reasonable alternative to the `sleep`. What is the reason you want to avoid blocking? I would call `sleep` blocking as well - you are not doing anything on the thread while it is sleeping. Can you show some more code you want to perform meanwhile?

Comment: I think you've got a fundamental contradiction here. You say you want a *non-blocking* way for the main thread to *block* until another thread finishes.

Comment: yes, you're right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing "non-blocking" about `sleep` :)
If you want your thread to idle until an asynchronous task completes, you have to block it (that's what blocking means). `Await.result` is exactly what you want.

Alternatively, you can set up a monitor and `wait` on it with something like:

```
 Future { runQuery(conn) }
   .onComplete { result => 
      result match {
         case Success(r) => println(r.next)
         case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
      }
      synchronized { notifyAll }
   }

 synchronized { wait }
```

But really, it is the same thing as `Await.result`, only clumsier.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object WaitFuture {
  @tailrec
  def checkFutureComplete[T](f: => Future[T]): Unit = {
    if(f.isCompleted) ()
    else checkFutureComplete(f)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val k = Future {
    Thread.sleep(12000)
    println("Coming")
    10
  }
    checkFutureComplete(k)
    println(k)
    val k2 = k
    println(k2)
  }
}
//
//Coming
//Future(Success(10))
//Future(Success(10))
```

Futures are non-blocking and asynchronous tasks. And only when you `Await` on them you can convert `(Future[T] => T)`. As posted by @Dima above this approach is also similar to Await.result, Where in we tail-recursively check the status of future. Even though we check we can never get the T value, but instead we can only achieve `Future(Success(T))` without `Await`.